# Render BitTorrent/Transmission bitfield

Tags: javascript, bit-fields, bittorrent

I'm trying to render a BitTorrent (transmission) bitfield into a chart like the following:

[image]

I'm getting my bitfield from the `pieces` field of the [Transmission RPC API](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/browser/trunk/extras/rpc-spec.txt).

My code right now looks like the following:

```
import BitField from 'bitfield'; // npm@bitfield
import { Buffer } from 'buffer'; // npm@buffer
import { splitEvery } from 'ramda'; // npm@ramda

const pieceCount = 11889;
const pieces = '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';

function renderPieces(pieces, width = 1000) {
  const colors = {
    gray: "#C8C7C9",
    accent: "#007DD7",
  };

  const buffer = Buffer.from(pieces, "base64");
  const bitfield = new BitField(buffer);

  const cellsCount = Math.pow(18, 2);

  const bits = [];
  bitfield.forEach((bit) => bits.push(bit));

  const cells = splitEvery(bits.length / cellsCount, bits).map(
    (chunk) => ((100 / chunk.length) * chunk.filter(Boolean).length) / 100
  );

  const strokeWidth = width / 100;
  const cellSize = width / 18;

  const cellsMarkup = splitEvery(18, cells)
    .map((row, rowIndex) =>
      row.map((alpha, colIndex) => {
        const fill = alpha < 0.1 ? colors.gray : colors.accent;
        const opacity = alpha < 0.1 ? 1 : Math.max(0.5, alpha);
        const size = cellSize - strokeWidth * 2;
        return `<rect fill="${fill}" fill-opacity="${opacity}" x="${colIndex * cellSize + strokeWidth}" y="${
          rowIndex * cellSize
        }" width="${size}" height="${size}" rx="${strokeWidth}" ry="${strokeWidth}" />`;
      })
    )
    .flat()
    .join("");

  return `<svg style="width: 100%;" viewBox="0 0 ${width} ${width}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    ${cellsMarkup}
  </svg>`;
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-haze-971p1e?file=/src/index.js

Output:

[image]

The problem is that the resulting graph doesn't match with the one rendered for the same bitfield by Transmission (Mac):

[image]

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: I added my progress. @0stone0

Comment: Are you sure that this bitfield represents that image? And your code is counting bits in a 32-bit integer, while you have 36.7 bits per pixel.

Comment: I'm quite sure it is, at least that's what I get from the spec description. How should I fix the 32-bit issue?

Comment: I mean did you pause the download before you grabbed that chart and bitfield. The chart only shows 2 distinct shades of blue, but that bitfield seem to a lot more dispersed. And is that chart showing "Progress" or "Available"? I don't think you can get availability from RPC API.

Comment: @gre_gor yes it was paused, the chart shows "progress"

Comment: How are you sure the pieces view is updated?  As far as I'm aware, it's not updated in realtime, and the code seems to suggest it's only updated on first view, and some other edge cases, not on a timer.  So, it could be showing out of date information.

Comment: @AnonCoward The download was paused